# How to restart a game in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm new to Phaser 3 as well as game development then I have a problem here. I'm trying to restart a game scene but I get an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: this.scene.restart is not a function" when I run this

```
var playbtn = this.add.dom(390, 600).createFromCache('play-btn');

    playbtn.setPerspective(600);

    playbtn.addListener('click');

    playbtn.on('click', function (event) {
        this.scene.restart();
    });
```

And this is my whole code

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Making your first Phaser 3 Game - Part 10</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.24.1/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 300 },
            debug: false
        }
    },
    dom: {
        createContainer: true
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update,
        hitbomb: hitBomb
    }
};
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);


var player;
var stars;
var bombs;
var platforms;
var cursors;
var score = 0;
var gameOver = false;
var scoreText;

var level_state;
var level = 1;

var de_star = 0;
var element;
var playbtn;


function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
    this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
    this.load.image('star', 'assets/bomb.png');
    this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/star.png');
    this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
    this.load.html('play-btn', 'assets/play.html');
    this.load.html('nameform', 'assets/loginform.html');
   
}

function create ()
{

    //  A simple background for our game
    this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');

    //  The platforms group contains the ground and the 2 ledges we can jump on
    platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

    //  Here we create the ground.
    //  Scale it to fit the width of the game (the original sprite is 400x32 in size)
    platforms.create(400, 568, 'ground').setScale(2).refreshBody();

    //  Now let's create some ledges
    platforms.create(600, 400, 'ground');
    platforms.create(50, 250, 'ground');
    platforms.create(750, 220, 'ground');

    // The player and its settings
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'dude');

    //  Player physics properties. Give the little guy a slight bounce.
    player.setBounce(0.2);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

    //  Our player animations, turning, walking left and walking right.
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'left',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 0, end: 3 }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'turn',
        frames: [ { key: 'dude', frame: 4 } ],
        frameRate: 20
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'right',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 5, end: 8 }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
    });

    //  Input Events
    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    //  Some stars to collect, 12 in total, evenly spaced 70 pixels apart along the x axis
    stars = this.physics.add.group({
        key: 'star',
        repeat: 1,
        setXY: { x: 12, y: 0, stepX: 70 }
    });

    stars.children.iterate(function (child) {
        //  Give each star a slightly different bounce
        child.setBounceY(Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.4, 0.8));

    });

    bombs = this.physics.add.group();

    //  The score
    scoreText = this.add.text(16, 16, 'score: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000' });
    level_state = this.add.text(16, 50, 'Level: 1', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000' });


    //  Collide the player and the stars with the platforms
    this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);
    this.physics.add.collider(stars, platforms);
    this.physics.add.collider(bombs, platforms);

    //  Checks to see if the player overlaps with any of the stars, if he does call the collectStar function
    this.physics.add.overlap(player, stars, collectStar, null, this);

    this.physics.add.collider(player, bombs, hitBomb, null, this);
}

function update ()
{
    if (gameOver)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
        player.setVelocityX(-160);

        player.anims.play('left', true);
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
        player.setVelocityX(160);

        player.anims.play('right', true);
    }
    else
    {
        player.setVelocityX(0);

        player.anims.play('turn');
    }

    if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down)
    {
        player.setVelocityY(-330);
    }
}

function collectStar (player, star)
{
    star.disableBody(true, true);

    //  Add and update the score
    score += 10;
    scoreText.setText('Score: ' + score);
    if (de_star==12)
    {
        gameOver = True;
    }
    else if (stars.countActive(true) === 0)
    {

        de_star+=1;
        stars = this.physics.add.group({
        key: 'star',
        repeat: 11-de_star,
        setXY: { x: 12, y: 0, stepX: 70 }
        });

        this.physics.add.collider(stars, platforms);

        stars.children.iterate(function (child) {

        //  Give each star a slightly different bounce
        child.setBounceY(Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.4, 0.8));

        });

        //  A new batch of stars to collect
        stars.children.iterate(function (child) {

            child.enableBody(true, child.x, 0, true, true);

        });

        this.physics.add.overlap(player, stars, collectStar, null, this);

        var x = (player.x < 400) ? Phaser.Math.Between(400, 800) : Phaser.Math.Between(0, 400);

        level += 1;

        var bomb = bombs.create(x, 16, 'bomb');
        bomb.setBounce(1);
        bomb.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
        bomb.setVelocity(Phaser.Math.Between(-200, 200), 20);
        bomb.allowGravity = false;

    }
    level_state.setText('Level: '+level);
}

function hitBomb (player, bomb)
{
    this.physics.pause();

    player.setTint(0xff0000);

    player.anims.play('turn');

    gameOver = true;

    var playbtn = this.add.dom(390, 600).createFromCache('play-btn');

    playbtn.setPerspective(600);

    playbtn.addListener('click');

    playbtn.on('click', function (event) {
        this.scene.restart();
    });
    
    this.tweens.add({
        targets: playbtn,
        y: 300,
        duration: 3000,
        ease: 'Power3'
    });
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When the character hits the bomb, the "Play Again" button will pop up, then the game will restart if the player hits that button. These are the things that I aim for...
The project I'm working on is a tutorial example but any advice or solution would help me a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Phaser, but probably `this` inside the event handler refers to the button. Use a fat arrow to bind the handler function to `this` from the surrounding scope:

```
    playbtn.on('click', (event) => {
        this.scene.restart();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked. However, my game after restarting doesn't receive any input as an event that means the character just stands stiff, I can't control him at all. I don't know if i have to remove that 'click' event of playbtn or something like that. Wish you could give me one more solution, Phaser is completely new to me.

Comment: @deone You should open a new question for that, if you haven't figured it out already.

Answer (score 2):

As @Thomas already point out, it's a problem of `this`.

You could use a fat arrow

```
    playbtn.on('click', (event) => {
        this.scene.restart();
    });
```

or you could pass the context to the 'on' function, i think it's 'game' looking at your code.

```
    playbtn.on('click', function (event) {
        this.scene.restart();
    }, game);
```

Here a snippet from the documentation of Phaser's `on`

```
    /**
     * Add a listener for a given event.
     * @param event The event name.
     * @param fn The listener function.
     * @param context The context to invoke the listener with. Default this.
     */
    on(event: string | symbol, fn: Function, context?: any): this;
```